# Expressão lógica que controla repetição

Tags: python, while

Estou resolvendo um exercício em Python que pede ao usuário que dê um palpite, sobre qual número o programa obteve para `pc` aleatoriamente.

```
from random import randint
tent = int(input('PALPITE:'))
pc = randint(0,4)
cont = 0
while tent != pc:
    pc = randint(0,4)
    tent  = int(input('Você errou! o numero que o pc escoheu foi {}.  Tente novamente '.format(pc)))


print('Parabens!Você acertou! o Número que o o computador escolheu foi {}.'.format(pc))
```

O código até que funciona, mas quando eu acerto o número ele diz que está errado. Quando eu coloco o `input` que está dentro do `while` para ser executando antes (em vez de randomizar o número primeiro) o resultado dá certo.

Sei que isso tem a ver com a estrutura sequencial, mas eu achei que se eu utilizasse o `randint` na variável `pc` dentro do `while` primeiro daria o mesmo resultado.

Por que isso acontece? Tem a ver com a expressão lógica lá em cima? É obrigatório eu ter recebido o valor do `input` dentro da variável primeiro para depois o Python analisar?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

O código é um pouco confuso e comete um erro que eu sempre vejo por aí. Um iniciante comete por desconhecer e o experiente comete porque acha que não pode usar nenhuma forma de `goto`, aí ele fica com raiva do `break` que faz isso e pra evitá-lo, faz código repetitivo que piora a chance de boa manutenção (nem tanto em código simples assim, mas vai ensinando a pessoa fazer errado em casos mais complexos).

Então só vou pedir o palpite dentro do laço, uma única vez. E vou separar o pedido de palpite da mensagem de erro. Quando errar, a mensagem aparece e pede o palpite novamente. Quando acertar encerra o laço e diz que acertou.

Estou imaginando que em cada tentativa deve ser sorteado outro número, caso deve ser o mesmo então o sorteio deveria estar fora do laço. Tinha um contador não usado que eu tirei, se iria us-a´lo mesmo aumenta a chance de que o sorteio deveria ser único e não mudar a cada tentativa.

Simples e limpo:

```
from random import randint

while True:
    pc = randint(0, 4)
    tent = int(input('PALPITE:'))
    if tent == pc:
        break
    print('Você errou! O número que o PC escolheu foi {}. Tente novamente '.format(pc))
print('Parabens! Você acertou! O número que o computador escolheu foi {}.'.format(pc))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gdKE09). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TestExitpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/TestExit.py).

Com contador talvez fosse assim:

```
from random import randint

pc = randint(0, 4)
contador = 0
while True:
    contador += 1
    tent = int(input('PALPITE:'))
    if tent == pc:
        break
    print('Você errou! Tente novamente '.format(pc))
print('Parabens! Você acertou em {} tentativas! O número que o computador escolheu foi {}.'.format(contador, pc))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QiSrnp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TestExit2py). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/TestExit2.py).